# Sum a value from diferent sheets and return the result on same cell

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to sum a cell from different sheets but I want the sum to be on the same cell or at least the result. The cell that is first summing, is gonna get deleted after the sum.

In this case, the cell `A1` is gonna get deleted.

The code only pastes the formula but doesn't do it.

```
Private Sub C2_Click()
    Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").Formula = "Sum(Prueba!A1, Reporte!C5)"
End Sub
```

No error messages though.

Comment: Formulas must start with `=`, so you should use something like: `....Formula = "=Sum(Pr...`. That said, you will end up with a circular reference which will probably cause unexpected results. You would be better off using `Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").Value + Sheets("Reporte").Range("C5").Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as Cybernetic.Nomad said you need to use the equal sing `=` in from of the formula you want. Remember, this is like you where typing in the cell that formula.

Another tip: you can use this

```
Private Sub C2_Click()
    Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").value= Evaluate("=Sum(Prueba!A1, Reporte!C5)
End Sub
```

This way you tell VBA to get the value returned from the SUM and put it inside the cell `A1` as a value, not formula.

Another tip:

```
Private Sub C2_Click()
    Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").Formula= "=SUM(Prueba:Reporte!A1:C5)"
End Sub
```

This way you can SUM across the sheets and all the sheets in between those sheets any value in the range A1:C5. Where you have "`Prueba`", "`Pueba01`", "`Pueba02`", "`Prueba03`" and "`Reporte`", all the values in the range `A1:C5`, in the sheets **between "`Prueba`" and "`Reporte`" will be summed**. If there is any other sheet outside this to sheets wont be summed in the result.

Also you can use:

```
Private Sub C2_Click()
    Sheets("Prueba").Range("A1").value= Evaluate("=SUM(Prueba:Reporte!A1:C5)")
End Sub
```